# NullReferenceException when subscribing to an event in the user control on the main form

Tags: c#, events, user-controls, nullreferenceexception

On my `User Control` I have created an event to notify my main form that a tab control must switch its tab. This event must be triggered on a button's click on the user control. (I have a very similar event in another User Control that is working fine)

**In my user control:**

```
public delegate void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs args);
public event EventHandler TabChangeRequested = delegate { };

protected void OnTabChangeRequested()
{
    if (TabChangeRequested != null)
    {
        TabChangeRequested(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}

private void btnBackToSelectType_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.OnTabChangeRequested();
}
```

**In my main form:**

```
public FormMain()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    myUserControl.TabChangeRequested += (sender, args) => { ChangeRunTabToType(); };           
}

private void ChangeRunTabToType()
{
    if (this != null)
        this.ChangeTabIndex(metroTabControlRun, 1);
}
```

When I run my program I get a `NullReferenceException` on the line

```
myUserControl.TabChangeRequested += (sender, args) => { ChangeRunTabToType(); };
```

Does anyone know where it comes from?

Comment: When is myUserControl instantiated ?

Comment: @Bun you are right! myUserControl is instantiated later in the program. So that is why I get this exception. Can you show me how I let my main form subscribe to this event even though my user control is not yet instantiated? I mean is there a way my main main form can subscribe after this user control is instantiated? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you really need to do it without instantiating the form you could use a static property on the second form... But why would you want to subscribe to something that doesn't exist :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If myUserControl isn't instantiated yet (and that's what is null), then I'd recommend moving:

```
myUserControl.TabChangeRequested += (sender, args) => { ChangeRunTabToType(); };
```

to after where you are creating/assigning myUserControl!